# Can I get SpecFlow to generate a list of missing step definitions without running the tests?

Tags: specflow

I'm in the process of refactoring our SpecFlow-implemented BDD tests. As part of this work, I've commented out most of the step definitions.

As I run the tests, I'm presented with the "No matching step definition found for one or more steps." message.

However, I'd prefer not to wait until the tests are actually run. Is there a way to get SpecFlow to check for missing step definitions without running the tests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `stepdefinitionreport` parameter to SpecFlow.exe, as follows:

```
specflow.exe stepdefinitionreport MyTests.csproj
```

But be aware:

1. If your assembly uses the .NET 4.0 runtime, you'll need to add a `specflow.exe.config` file with a `<supportedRuntime>` element.
2. It uses some functionality that's 32-bit only. So if you're on 64-bit Windows, you'll need to use `CORFLAGS /32BIT+` to edit the `Specflow.exe` file.
3. By default, it looks in the `bin\Debug` folder.

Comment: I wrote about that a couple of months ago here: http://www.marcusoft.net/2010/12/know-where-you-stepgenerate-step.html